# I need to hide shipping class from shop page

Tags: css

Anyone could help me with shipping classes?
I need to hide them from shop page, but to show on product page.
I'm using "Show Shipping Class in Product Page" plugin to show it in product page, but its automatically shown in the shop as well. I need to hide it from the shop view.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So, am I getting you right? You are talking about the Plugin WooComerce in Wordpress?

Comment: Im using wordpress plugin but i need help with css to hide shipping class from shop page

Comment: It would be much clearer to help you if you give some more information. Add which platform/framework/stack/code example/... you're using.

Comment: related? https://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-shipping-class-at-single-product-page/